# Cannot connect Player (iPhone 8 iOS 13.1) to visual studio for mac 2019

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, ios13, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to debug my VR application built in Unity using Visual studio for Mac 2019. But I am not able to connect my iPhone device to the Unity Debugger in VS. I enabled the “Development Build” , ”Script Debugging” and “Wait For Managed Debugger” options before building the Player. But it still doesn't work.

My Build Settings in Unity: 
[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsWX0.png)

Build Settings My Unity Debugger Attach to Process Window: 
[Attach to Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4a6H.png)

I also tried to connect the player over TCP connection from unity console (note: I put my laptop and my iPhone on airplane mode and both were connected to the same wifi network) but I keep getting the error "Failed to connect to player".

Am I missing out something here ? Is my phone blocking the connectivity?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue on an iOS 14.8 (18H17) iPhone 12 device. The Unity Player is successfully listed in Visual Studio 'Attach To Process' when following identical steps using an IOS 12.5.1 (16H22) iPhone 6 device, so the issue is either with the iOS version or the device.